# Toggling input with one parent .click() action

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm having trouble trying to find the proper way to make it work :

I got a table that with multiple cells :

```
$('tr > td').click(function()
```

each time the cell is clicked, I add to this cell an input and 2 buttons (one button is to validate, other one is to delete the whole thing in the cell so it deletes the input and both buttons)

The problem is when I click on the delete button it also triggers the

```
$('tr > td').click(function()
```

so what it does is that it removes the input and the 2 buttons but add it back.

what I need is that :

if cell is empty : add input + 2 buttons
if remove button is clicked : remove input + 2 buttons from the cell
cell can only have 1 time the input and 2 buttons (so no multiples inputs and more than 2 buttons)

I've been trying to make it right by using toggleClass and using if statement with hasClass
but it never goes as I want to.

Thanks for your help, hope you can fill my lack of logic.

EDIT :

```
   function remove()
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('removed');
    $(this).prev().prev().remove();
    $(this).next().next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
}
    $('tr > td').click(function(event)
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass("done") == false && $(this).hasClass("removed") == false)
        {
            $(this).toggleClass("done");
            $(this).append("<input class='form-control' style='height:25px;width:105px;' type='text'></input>");
            $(this).append("<button onclick='remove();' type='button' id='removeUser' class='btn btn-xs'><span class='text-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>");
            $(this).append("<button type='submit' id='addUser' class='btn btn-xs'><span class='text-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></button>");
        }
```

TD can only have 1 [input+2buttons]

If remove button is clicked, [input+2buttons] is removed

If TD is clicked and TD is empty, add [input+2buttons]

Sorry for being late it was launch time :)

Comment: stop propagation on buttons click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

This prevent the click being triggered on the parent of the button too. So, when you click on your button, use this function to avoid the click being triggered on the td as well

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevincittadini/jPX6y/1/)

If you remove the `e.stopPropagation` also the alert on the div will appear. So, now you know how to use it.

Remember to change your button click handler from `.click(function(){...` to `.click(function(event){...` or `.click(function(e){...` as I did in the demo, so you can use the method.

**EDIT to answer your EDIT**

Change  this

```
$('tr > td').click(function(event)
{
```

to this

```
$('tr > td').click(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
```

and remove `event.stopPropagation` from the `remove()` function please.

Comment: But if it's removed it has to add [input+2 buttons] again how ?

Comment: Your problem was about event bubbling. Did you try to fix your code using these suggestions? Are you asking us to provide you the full code of what are you trying to do? Can you explain better? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be on the remove function ? since the [input+2buttons] are child of the parent <td>

Comment: Yes but it'll work anyway, i don't want to completely change your code to do something that'll work fine anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

further reading : [Event bubling and capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing/4616720#4616720)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('tr > td').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();

  alert("The  element was clicked.");

});
```